# how to convert a string number with leading 0 to a double in c#

Tags: c#, string, forms, type-conversion, double

so I'm trying to convert a string number with leading 0 to a double and output it to my textbox, but I keep getting a "cannot simply convert a type double to the string".

i tried these 2 ways but it does not work:

```
Double.TryParse(090015.40, out time1);
System.Console.WriteLine("time1 " + time1);

time2 = Convert.ToDouble(090015.60);
System.Console.WriteLine("time2 " + time2);

//textBox_time1.Text = time1;//"cannot simply convert a type double to the string" error
//textBox_time2.Text = time2;//"cannot simply convert a type double to the string" error
```

current output on the console:

```
time1 90015.4
time2 90015.6
```

output I want:

```
time1 090015.4
time2 090015.6
```

Comment: you can call `.ToString("000000.0")` on your numbers

Comment: [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) for more options if needed.

Comment: Does converting string to a double and then to a string again make sense in this case?

Comment: Still need an answer for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first things first lets explain the error you are getting. The error occurs because the `textBox_time1.Text` and `textBox_time2.Text` properties require a string rather than a double. You can see details of this over at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.text?view=netcore-3.1).

Secondly, to fix the both the error and the problem you are looking to solve you can, as has been suggested by Lucian, use `.ToString("000000.0")` which will format the number to the string formula provided and restore the leading zero.

I will say, I question how beneficial it is to continue using a leading zero on a number you've converted, and also will say that using the formula above to restore the leading zero could lead to issues if the number you are converting back to a string is longer than the formula allows.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to convert a string into a double/int/float when you need them for mathematic operations like +,-,*,/. If you only want to show them on screen (into a textbox or something like that), you only need the string of the number. Here an example:

---

```
    private static void ConvertTest()
    {
        string myString = "13.45";
        double myDouble1; //myDouble1 = 0
        double myDouble2; //myDouble2 = 0


        Double.TryParse(myString, out myDouble1); //myDouble1 = 13.45
        myDouble2 = Convert.ToDouble(myString); //myDouble2 = 13.45

        Console.WriteLine(myDouble1); //Prints a string

        Console.WriteLine(myDouble1 + myDouble2); //Prints the sum of the doubles

        Console.WriteLine(myDouble1.ToString() + myDouble2.ToString()); //Prints the first double and then the second --> 13.4513.45

    }
```

---

**Hope it helps**

Answer (score -1):

If you want the output to be a double, you can't have any zeros in the front. This can only be outputted in a string in that way. The internal representation of the double format does not include leading zeros.

Comment: I thought that would be the case, I guess a workaround would just be to add a zero in front in the textbox and leave it as a string

Comment: There is no indication OP wants to "keep the zero" the only requirement is to have format with zero at the beginning as shown in `Lucian Bumb` comment. "090015.4" is perfectly reasonable `double` and can be easily printed with `90015.4d.ToString("000000.0")`. I suspect you tried to explain that internal representation of double does not keep leading zeros... You probably should [edit] the answer to clarify that.